# Make [piracy-prevention] and [piracy-protection] walk the plank!

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Today while sailing the seas of Stack Overflow, I came across the ports of [piracy-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy-prevention) and [piracy-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy-protection). In these shipyards, I discovered all kinds of questions, but nothing to convince me that these tags add anything of value.

When confronted about their purpose, only [piracy-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy-protection) managed to reply with a feeble:

> Strategies to protect an application / software from being copied or used without permission.

---

These be the reasons this tag is not useful, based on [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191):

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

They are ambiguous, and attempts to cover a hopelessly broad topic, which involves anything from trying to stop web-scrapers to legal action.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Programming related topics under this blanket can be on-topic, however the tag cannot stand on its own for any questions that would be considered on-topic.

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No. Many tags exist for the various technologies commonly used as anti-piracy measures ([obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/obfuscation), [drm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drm), etc.). These would add something meaningful, not a blanket tag for all of them.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Both tags are meant to cover anti-piracy techniques, but the actual purpose for using such a tag will depend on the question.

---

These ports currently contain [56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy-prevention) and [32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy-protection) questions in their harbors. I say we throw the [piracy-prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy-prevention) and [piracy-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piracy-protection) tags overboard, and send them down to Davy Jones' locker! Who be with me?!?

P.S. I know discussing two tags at once is generally a bad idea, but these tags mean the exact same thing.

Comment: Let's throw [anti-piracy] and [piracy] overboard too, while we're at it.

Comment: @JonasCz Clearly [tag:piracy] deserves a keelhauling

Comment: Poor pirates, but yeah.

Comment: It would be helpful if you directly answer the questions.  As it is now, your answers are full of opinion and commentary.

Comment: I think a tag for the broader topic can still have a use, as well as more specific tags such as [drm]. There should be one canonical tag and not multiple ones.  There's also [software-protection]. Perhaps the [anti-piracy] tag can be the canonical one?